# Why did auto-py-to-exe create so many files and such a large application?

Tags: python, exe, filesize, auto-py-to-exe

I used auto-py-to-exe to create an application out of a project I made.  The total size of the required files is about 40MB.  The libraries imported are

```
-pandas
-sklearn.svm
-pickle 
-joblib
-warnings
-tkinter
```

When I clicked "convert my .py to .exe", the program loaded a bunch of files.  The final application folder is about 3GB.  When I looked inside the application folder, there seemed to be a bunch of unnecessary modules and libraries, but I'm not sure.  For example, there is a subdirectory called tensorflow, but I didn't use tensorflow at all in my project.  I didn't create a custom working environment.  The application works fine, but I would like to get the size of my application down to something reasonable.

Comment: You could also try using PyInstaller to build your exe.

Comment: Would that be easier to use and not build such a large exe?

Comment: @101 auto-py-to-exe uses pyinstaller

Comment: @PhillipFeldman auto-py-exe is just a gui for pyinstaller.  You should create a virtual environment for you project and only install what is necessary for the project and then run pyinstaller.